# How to set precision to a number

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "include/Parser.h"
#include </usr/local/include/mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include "/usr/local/include/mysql++/cmdline.h"
#include </usr/include/mysql/mysql_version.h>
#include "/usr/lib/jsoncpp/include/json/json.h"

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    Json::Value lat = parser["geo"]["lat"];
    cout << "latitude = " <<lat.toStyledString()<< endl;
}
```

After passing value to this argument my latitude value is 42.3577770 .I want to make it 42.35 how can I do that?

I tried

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed <<  lat.toStyledString() << '\n';
```

But it's not working. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Well it won't. AFAIK `.setprecision` applies to floats, your function returns a string.

Comment: conversion to the string happens in lat.toStyledString(). That's why setprecision doesn't work. Send your lat as double to cout and you'll get the expected results

Comment: can you teach me how to do that ??

Comment: I'd reverse fixed and setprecision(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << lat.asDouble() << '\n';
```

(According to online documentation of Json::Value)

Comment: thanks it works .it gives me value 42.36 but i want 42.35 .do you have any suggestion for that ? Thanks again

Comment: floor(lat.asDouble() * 100.0) / 100.0

Answer (score 0):

You want to drop the `toStyledString()` and work with a `float`:

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << lat << '\n';
```

Comment: how to send lat as double to cout ?